# How do I get text of parent and its parent on clicking a navbar tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I **click A1-810** I am getting **output** as

```
A1-810
ICONIA A-SERIES
```

**Now I want output as**

```
A1-810
ICONIA A-SERIES
Acer
```

**Jquery Code**
Kindly ignore closing brackets

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".list-unstyled a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
        var anchortext = $(this).text();
        var parenttext = $(this).closest("ul").prev("a").text();
        console.log(anchortext , parenttext)
         });
          });
```

**HTML CODE**

```
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-togg main">Cellphone Parts</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                  <div class="dropdown-inner">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-togg">Acer</a>
                        <div class="nav-dropdown-content">
                          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-togg"
                                >ICONIA A-SERIES</a
                              >
                              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">A1-810</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A1-830</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                   </li>
                                  </ul>
                                 </div>
                                </li>
                               </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that I've tried to make bullet proof.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-unstyled a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
    var anchortext = $(this).text();
    var parentText = [];
    parentText = getParentText($(this), parentText, 1);
    //var parenttext = $(this).closest("ul").prev("a").text();
    console.log(anchortext, parentText.join(", "))
  });

  function getParentText(ele, arr, count = 0) {
    var f = false;
    var i = 0;
    while (!f && i < 10 && count > 0) {
      if ($(ele).parent().prev("a").length > 0) {
        arr.push($(ele).parent().prev("a").text())
        f = true;
      }
      ele = $(ele).parent();
      i++;
    }
    if (f && count > 0) {
      arr = getParentText(ele, arr, (count - 1));
    }
    return arr;
  }
});
```

The function `getParentText` takes 3 parameters (2 required and 1 optional)

`ele` is the element we want to search from.
`arr` is the array where we want to added the results to.
`count` is how many times we want to loop.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-unstyled a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
    var anchortext = $(this).text();
    var parentText = [];
    parentText = getParentText($(this), parentText, 2);
    //var parenttext = $(this).closest("ul").prev("a").text();
    console.log(anchortext, parentText.join(", "))
  });

  function getParentText(ele, arr, count = 0) {
    var f = false;
    var i = 0;
    while (!f && i < 10 && count > 0) {
      if ($(ele).parent().prev("a").length > 0) {
        arr.push($(ele).parent().prev("a").text())
        f = true;
      }
      ele = $(ele).parent();
      i++;
    }
    if (f && count > 0) {
      arr = getParentText(ele, arr, (count - 1));
    }
    return arr;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-togg main">Cellphone Parts</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
      <div class="dropdown-inner">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-togg">Acer</a>
            <div class="nav-dropdown-content">
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-togg">ICONIA A-SERIES</a>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">A1-810</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A1-830</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think he's just started. When he'll learn some more he'll understand the value of your answer. It's a very good solution :)

Comment: @ShafikulIslam I agree with you that it could be a bit hard to understand for a new person, But I wanted to give a solution that he could use no matter how big the "tree" was.

Comment: yes I understand that, that's why I up voted your answer dear.

Comment: @UmarNazaket I'm not sure I understand what you mean by CELL PARTS, but I would advice you to slow down a bit. Think about what you have, what you get and how can I make it work so i get the next bit of information you want.

Comment: CELL PARTS is the previous text in the HTML navbar code. See 3rd line of the HTML code. So what I want is to get all the parent texts.

Comment: @UmarNazaket if you click on `A1-810` and you want to get the top text `Cellphone Parts` then you just need to change the last number in `getParentText($(this), parentText, 2);` to  3

Comment: Thanks, a lot sir, It helped a lot. I am a designer so I often get stuck in these things. Highly appreciated how you explained and gave the answer.

Comment: @UmarNazaket No problem

Answer (score 2):

```
var parentParentText = $(this).closest("ul").prev("a").closest("ul").parent().prev("a").text();
```

Comment: I don't know why OP removed the answer from yours to mine, yours is the most correct for new people and his case. I'll +1 yours.

Comment: Because yours was future proof and that's what he did wanted but couldn't explained I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like below,

```
$(".list-unstyled a").on("click", function(e) {
        Array.from($(e.target).parentsUntil('.dropdown-menu').find('a.dropdown-togg:first-of-type')).reverse().forEach(a=>console.log(a.textContent)});
```